# Envíos de email con laravel de diferentes correos

Tags: laravel, email

tengo la siguiente duda, necesito enviar correos desde diferentes cuenta desde mi app de laravel. Entiendo y se, que en el .env declaro el usuario y pass del mail que utiliza la aplicación.
Pero como puedo hacer esto de forma variable?, y utilizar la configuración del correo que necesite en cada caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar cambios en la configuracion desde el codio Laravel tiene el helper " Config " y lo usarias de la digiente manera

```
Config::set('key', 'value');
```

Entonces si quieres cambiar el usuario de los correos seria:

```
Config::set('mail.username', "example@mail.com");
Config::set('mail.password', "******");
```

Aunque otra opción para hacer lo que necesitan es, en vez de cambiar la configuracion de los correos, Laravel te da la opcion de enmascarar el correo de salida usando la funcion "
from ".

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel'); //correo y nombre de remitente

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com'); //correo del receptor
});
```

Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a revisar.
El "From" no me sirve, ya que necesito que el email quede en la bandeja de salida.
Saludos.